# What does the "gi" library stand for?

Tags: python, gtk

What does the "gi" library stand for? I am thinking "Graphical Interface" but didn't get confirmation here  https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/api/api.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It stands for "GObject Introspection".

[This](https://gi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) site states the term explicitly and mentions the Python module.